# Regex to validate number and letter sequence

Tags: regex

I want a regex to validate inputs of the form AABBAAA, where A is a a letter (a-z, A-Z) and B is a digit (0-9). All the As must be the same, and so must the Bs.

Comment: Just in case you haven't been there before http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all the *A*'s and *B*'s are supposed to be the same, I think the only way to do it would be:

```
([a-zA-Z])\1([0-9])\2\1\1\1
```

Where *\1* and *\2* refer to the first and second parenthetical groupings.  However, I don't think all regex engines support this.

Comment: +1 for backreferences, supported by at least Basic and Extended POSIX REs and perl.  While probably *not* what the questioner wants, it is a valid reading of the question.

Comment: True. This way `AB12CDE` will not match but `AA11AAA` will; I doubt that's what the OP wants, but it very well could be.

Answer (score 6):

It's really not as hard as you think; you've got most of the syntax already.

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}
```

The numbers in braces (`{}`) tell how many times to match the previous character or set of characters, so that matches `[a-zA-Z]` twice, `[0-9]` twice, and `[a-zA-Z]` three times.

**Edit:** If you want to make sure the matched string is not part of a longer string, you can use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html); just add `\b` to each end of the regex:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\b
```

Now "**Ab12Cde**" will match but "YZ**Ab12Cde**fg" will not.

**Edit 2:** Now that the question has changed, [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) are the only way to do it. edsmilde's answer should work; however, you may need to add the word boundaries to get your final solution.

```
\b([a-zA-Z])\1([0-9])\2\1\1\1\b
```

Comment: You can also use `\d{2}` instead of `[0-9]{2}`, depending on your preference.

Comment: Should this be anchored, to prohibit, say, BBAABBAAABB?

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}
```